# How to run lime test in Symfony plugin?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, symfony1, symfony-1.4, lime-unittest

I have a plugin in Symfony 1.4 and I have created for him some tests put them in `ROOT/myPlugin/test/unit/MyTest.php`

The plugin was generated with `sfTaskExtraPlugin`.

The content of `MyTest.php` is:

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../bootstrap/unit.php';
$t = new lime_test(1); 
$r = new My();
$v = $r->getSomething(2);
$t->is($v, true);         

?>
```

When I run  `./symfony test:unit Rights` the response is  `>> test      no tests found`

However if I copy `MyTest.php` file in `ROOT/test/unit` the command `./symfony test:unit Rights` is working.

The plugin is enabled in `ProjectConfiguration.class.php`

Why the test are not working if I write them in plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugin's tests are not run by default (for good reason - why would you want to run tests for a 3rd party plugin every time you want to test your app?).

Edit your ProjectConfiguration like this:

```
class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setup()
  {
    $this->enablePlugins('myPlugin');
  }

  public function setupPlugins()
  {
    $this->pluginConfigurations['myPlugin']->connectTests();
  }
}
```

this will run the given plugin's tests along with the project's. Taken from [symfony.com, about testing plugins](http://symfony.com/blog/about-testing-plugins).

Comment: Thank for the replay. I get this error now `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class ProjectConfiguration in ROOT/path/to/plugins/myPlugin/test/fixtures/project/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php on line 18`

Comment: Don't just copypaste my code in there - edit yours to look like it (substituting myPlugin for your plugins name, etc.)

Comment: Yes, this is what I did. I have put my plugin name in :  `$this->pluginConfigurations['MY_PLUGIN_NAME']->connectTests();`

Comment: According to the error, you did copypaste the whole stuff in there.

Comment: I think I  have copy them all. But note that in the error is pointing to `ProjectConfiguration.‌​class.php` from the plugin `ROOT/path/to/plugins/myPlugin/test/fixtures/project/config` not the main `config/ProjectConfiguration.‌​class.php`. Why is pointing there?

Comment: Oh, did not notice it. Did you add it there? It should be added to the main project configuration file.

Comment: Yes, it is in the main project configuration file. However, I get this error concerning other `ProjectConfiguration.‌​class.php` which is in `ROOT/path/to/plugins/myPlugin/test/fixtures/project/config/ProjectConfiguration.‌​class.php`. Strange...

Comment: That class (and file) should be called myPluginConfiguration, not ProjectConfiguration.